# AngularJs file upload showing error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload

I am using simple file upload code. Its showing error :

[image]

Here is my code :

```
<input type="file" name="student_image" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadFile(this.files)" ng-model="formData.studentImage" id="student_image">

$scope.uploadFile = function (files) {
        var form_data = new FormData();
        form_data.append("file", files[0]);
        $http.post('process.php', form_data, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        }).success(function (data) {
            if (data == "failed") {
                // if not successful, bind errors to error variables
                $scope.errorFinal = "Failed";
            } else {
                $scope.formData.image_name = data;
            }
        }).error('failed');
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
angular.element(this).scope().uploadFile(this);
```

.

```
<input type="file" name="student_image" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadFile(this)" ng-model="formData.studentImage" id="student_image">
```

JS

```
$scope.uploadFile = function(data){
    console.log(data.files[0]);
};
```